# DispatchTimer skipping interval seconds displayed in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having some trouble with my `DispatchTimer`. Every once in a while, it'll "skip" a second or two shown on my UI. It's started in my `MainViewModel` class where it displays a countdown in my view.

```
    public string Timer
    {
        get { return _timer; }
        set
        {
            _timer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Timer");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _countDownTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _countDownTimer.Tick += async (o, e) => await countdownTimer();
        _countDownTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
        _countDownTimer.IsEnabled = true;
        _countDownTimer.Start();

    }
```

And here's the method that is called when the countdown goes to zero:

```
    private async Task countdownTimer()
    {
        TimeSpan TimeRemaining = _next - DateTime.Now;

        string t = TimeRemaining.Hours + "h " + TimeRemaining.Minutes + "m " + TimeRemaining.Seconds + "s";
        this.Timer = t;  // display it on the UI
        int secondsRemaining = (int) TimeRemaining.TotalSeconds;

        if (secondsRemaining == 0)
        {
            // do something that takes a while
            await Task.Run(() => {
                refresIp();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Side note:**
The variable `_next` is simply 5 mins ahead. Once it goes to zero, it goes ahead another 5 mins from the current time: in other words, this countdown happens every 5 mins.

I'm not sure exactly what causes this "hickup", but maybe using `await` and `Task` is what's causing the issue versus using threads in this particular case. Though, from my understanding, is that you use `await` and `async` for something that can take a while waiting for the result, versus using threads to split up a particular task, hence why the use of `await` and `async`. Anyway, some insight would be great.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would explain the behavior you're seeing. Your description is consistent with something else blocking the UI thread for some period of time. The `DispatcherTimer` uses the UI thread and can only raise the `Tick` event when the UI thread is not busy doing something else. Even in this case, the code you have wouldn't "skip" seconds so much as just fail to update the display; you'll still get a 5 minute countdown. Once I elaborated enough on your code example to run it, it worked fine, without skipping any seconds.

Comment: Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this is as minimal as it gets and it is the exact code the reproduces the problem. I have no other way of rephrasing the question without being redundant and polluted with useless code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'll double check to see if there's nothing else missing here

Comment: Since you didn't include a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, there's clearly something missing. It's also the case that your problem description is imprecise. It's not clear whether you mean that you _literally_ see the countdown skipping 1 or 2 seconds (i.e. the 5 minute period is actually reduced by those 1 or 2 seconds that are skipped) or the display simply fails to update over some period of time. The latter is plausible, but there may or may not be anything you can do about it, depending on what's causing it. The former is implausible, given the code you've posted so far.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not losing any time, just the UI displays 4:40 and then goes to 4:37 without displaying the interval.

Comment: _"displays 4:40"_ -- as in, it shows that for three seconds? If so then, like I said, that's consistent with something blocking your UI thread for some period of time (like, three seconds). Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to provide an answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I figured it out. The counter.stop and count.start were called in the `refreshIp()` async method which was support to be set within  the UI  thread, causing this skip.

Comment: _"counter.stop and count.start were called in the refreshIp()"_ -- and was that critical detail included in your question? No. I hope you see now just how important it is that you make certain you've actually included a good **[mcve]** in your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, though sometimes when you spend so much time staring at code, you tend to forget details that were written quite a while ago. Oversight.

Comment: _"you tend to forget details that were written quite a while ago."_ -- doesn't matter. A good MCVE is one you've copied and pasted straight from a project made specifically for the purpose of the question. When done properly, what you recall is irrelevant. The code will necessarily be exactly what it needs to be.

Comment: @PeterDuniho copying directly from the code also has a downside: it's polluted and it fills up the question with lots of writing and it becomes an eye-sore. What happens after: " your question is too long and need to compress it; too much writing" and the question is put on Close or On Hold. Your first comment was what made me realize where I missed and was enough for me to correct the problem.

Comment: _"copying directly from the code also has a downside: it's polluted and it fills up the question with lots of writing and it becomes an eye-sore."_ -- only if you **copy the wrong code**. Please go read **[mcve]**. It explains clearly that no one expects or even wants you to copy your real-world code. Your job is to create a suitable MCVE for the purpose of the question, so you are copying (as I wrote above) **"from a project made specifically for the purpose of the question"**

Comment: @PeterDuniho I did read it. My problem had nothing to do with run-time errors or compilation errors, but a behavioral problem that I happen to notice by accident which did `not` break my application whatsoever. This is why I posted that code since I thought it was some underlying problem that I might have missed with my `DispatchTimer` and `await` and `async`. You `did` in fact help me because all I needed was: `"hey, something is probably blocking the UI thread`", and after looking further down into my code, the problem was solved.